# Calling DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I have set up my Dialog Fragment class successfully, and now I would like to call it from my main Fragment class I have set up.

I have tried using multiple code to call it, but I keep getting errors and crashes.

What would I need to put in my onClick to call my Dialog Fragment?

Thanks in advance!

Main Fragment Class:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment,
            container, false);

    mImageView = (RecyclingImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            //Here


        }

    });

    return v;
}
```

Dialog Fragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
Context mContext;

public MyDialogFragment() {
    mContext = getActivity();
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            mContext);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Set Wallpaper?");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
    // null should be your on click listener
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    return alertDialogBuilder.create();
}

public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
    return f;
}

}
```

Comment: Use this code to show dialog fragment  
MyDialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);

Comment: jack what is the use of `public static MyDialogFragment newInstance()` if you have  `MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling DialogFragment from Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252288/calling-dialogfragment-from-fragment)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38500468/3496570

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the solution:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_detail_fragment,
            container, false);

    mImageView = (RecyclingImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                MyDialogFragment dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
            dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
        }

    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: op has a static method newInstance() which returns the instance of the dialog fragment. SO why this `MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment()`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MyDialogFragment dialog = MydialogFragment.newInstance();
dialog.show(ft, "Tag");
```

Here is also a great [TUTORIAL](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

Comment: op has a static method `newInstance()` which returns the instance of the dialog fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dialog fragment you already have the below which returns the instance of dialog framgent.

```
public static MyDialogFragment newInstance() {
    MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
    return f;  
}
```

So try the below

```
DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();// call the static method
newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Look at the docs there is an example

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I called from my FragmentACtivity

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                ContactsNavi userPopUp = new ContactsNavi();
                userPopUp.show(fragmentManager,"baglantilar");
```