# Can you show me why these methods are out of scope?

Tags: java, android, class, scope

I am using a tutorial to create a download class and it uses a progress dialog. The show and dissmiss methods are in protected classes inside of the asynchTask class. The IDE is telling me that it can not resolve them

```
public class DownloadHandler {

    private Context mContext;
    public String filename;
    private String remotePath;

    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public DownloadHandler(String rp, String f, Context c) throws Exception {
    mContext = c;
    remotePath = rp;
    filename = f;
}

private void startDownload() {
    String url = "http://example.com/"+remotePath+"/"+filename+".pdf";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

//===================showDialog can not be resolved============================

        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
//========================================================================

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            //write it to the internal storage

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename+".pdf");


            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
//=========dismissDialog can not be resolved ==================

        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
//=============================================================
    }
}

}
```

Does it have something to do with the protected class?

Comment: I don't see those methods in the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Well, I don't know. That is how it was written in the tutorial. Now that I did a direct copy and paste without any mods, my IDE says those methods are deprecated.

Comment: Link me to the tutorial

Comment: If I extend Activity it is resolved but shows deprecated. Hang on, I will get the link.

Comment: @VinceEmigh http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`showDialog` and `dismissDialog` are in the `Activity` class. In the tutorial, it shows that the class `Download` extends activity, which the inner class can then use.

Have `Download` extend `Activity`. As for the methods being deprecated, this is because you should be using a `DialogFragment`. Apparently, the tutorial you are following is outdated, and you should look into [how to use a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20405684/2398375)