# Implementing a Callback for DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

From my `Recylerview Adapter`, there are multiple buttons in every Items, 
What I want is to show the `DialogFragment as confirmation` when they are clicked and execute a different methods/actions when the `positiveButton` is clicked.

The problem is I don't know how can I have or how can I implement a callback when the `positiveButton` is clicked and can execute a different methods or actions according to what button is to be clicked on every items.

`e.g.` On my Adapter Class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PageOnlineAdapter.TheViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(TITLE,CONTENT); //Initialize DialogFragment with a specific Title and Content
            newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)contextView).getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG); 
            /*
                if positiveButton is clicked
                    =>execute method/action here
            */
        }
    );

    holder.btn_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(TITLE,CONTENT); //Initialize DialogFragment with a specific Title and Content
            newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)contextView).getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG); 
            /*
                if positiveButton is clicked
                    =>execute method/action here
            */  
        }
    );

    holder.btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(TITLE,CONTENT); //Initialize DialogFragment with a specific Title and Content
            newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)contextView).getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG); 
            /*
                if positiveButton is clicked
                    =>execute method/action here
            */  
        }
    );

    holder.btn_remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(TITLE,CONTENT); //Initialize DialogFragment with a specific Title and Content
            newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)contextView).getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG); 
            /*
                if positiveButton is clicked
                    =>execute method/action here
            */ 
        }
    );
}
```

Here's my DialogFragment Class

```
public class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static ConfirmationDialog newInstance(String title, String description) {
        ConfirmationDialog frag = new ConfirmationDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        args.putString("description", description);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString("title");
        String description = getArguments().getString("description");
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                //.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(description)
                .setPositiveButton("CONTINUE",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                               //How to tell when this positiveButton is clicked
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                //How to tell when this negativeButton is clicked
                            }
                        }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you planning on doing different operations when positive is clicked in each button, or are you going to do the same in all of them?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to do a different operation when a postiveButton is clicked.

Comment: I'm surprised if the below solution wouldn't throw a null pointer if you rotated the screen with the dialog open and tried to callback. It's a dialog FRAGMENT as such it has its own lifecycle and you can implement the onAttach onDetach methods like you would a fragment - this is where you should be implementing an interface callback.  Callback to the Activity that provided the FragmentManager reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback to a Fragment from a DialogFragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to create an interface that is going to be implemented by the Adapter and passed to the dialogframe when creating it. The dialogframe could then invoke a certain method when positive is clicked and another one when negative is clicked :

```
public interface DialogCallback{

    void clickedPositiveStart();
    void clickedPositiveStop();
    void clickedNegativeStart();
    void clickedNegativeStop();
}




public class MyAdapter extends Adapter implements DialogCallback, View.OnClickListener{

   @Override
   protected void onClick(View view){
       DialogFragment newFragment =  null;
       String action;

       if(view.getId() == R.id.your_start_button){ 
           action = "start";
       }else if(view.getId() == R.id.your_stop_button){
           action = "stop";    
       }else if(..){
           ....
       }else{
           return;
       }

       newFragment = ConfirmationDialog.newInstance(TITLE,CONTENT, this, action);
       newFragment.show(((AppCompatActivity)contextView).getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG); 
   }

   @Override
   public void clickedPositiveStart(){
        // do something when positive is clicked
   }

   @Override
   public void clickedPositiveStop(){
        // do something when positive is clicked
   }

   @Override
   public void clickedNegativeStart(){
        // do something when negative is clicked
   }

   @Override
   public void clickedNegativeStop(){
        // do something when negative is clicked
   }

}


public ConfirmationDialog extends Dialogfragment{

    private DialogCallback callback;
    private String action;

    public static ConfirmationDialog newInstance(String title, String description, DialogCallback callback, String action) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.action = action;
        ...
    }


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    String description = getArguments().getString("description");
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            //.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(description)
            .setPositiveButton("CONTINUE",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                           if(action.equals("start"){
                              callback.clickedPositiveStart();
                           } else if(action.equals("stop"){
                              callback.clickedPositiveStop();
                           }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                           if(action.equals("start"){
                              callback.clickedNegativeStart();
                           } else if(action.equals("stop"){
                              callback.clickedNegativeStop();
                           }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .create();
     }
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your answer, But I can't really make it work, Can you adapt it into my snippet code?

Comment: @Polar Instead of executing code in your on-click event when the positive button is clicked, you execute it in the methods provided by the interface in your adapter class. This was just an example, I don't know what exactly you want to execute when the positive/negative button is clicked

Comment: @Polar I edited my post, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I though I can have a single model for a `DialogFragment` and call it inside the button and just return true or false if the `positiveButton` is clicked so I can perform other task inside the `onClickListerner` of every buttons. Anyway, thank you @MerveSahin.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I would like to say Thanks to [Merve Sahin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5703530/merve-sahin) for the idea of creating `Interface`.

Instead of the accepted answer, I endup using the below code. 
This makes me have one class of `DialogFragment` and used it for many cases `e.g.` `Calling by Multiple Buttons and response according to what button is clicked`.

First, You need to `import` the following:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

And for **AlertDialog**, Create a class:

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TITLE = "title", CONTENT = "content";
    private OnContinueCancelClick continueCancelClick;

    public static ConfirmDialog newInstance(String title, String content) {
        ConfirmDialog frag = new ConfirmDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TITLE, title);
        args.putString(CONTENT, content);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    public void setOnContinueCancelClick(OnContinueCancelClick continueCancelClick) {
        this.continueCancelClick = continueCancelClick;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = getArguments().getString(TITLE);
        String content = getArguments().getString(CONTENT);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(content)
                .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        if(continueCancelClick != null)
                            continueCancelClick.onCancelClicked();
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("CONTINUE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        if(continueCancelClick != null)
                            continueCancelClick.onContinueClicked();
                    }
                });
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;

    }

    //Declare an Interface
    public interface OnContinueCancelClick{
        void onContinueClicked();
        void onCancelClicked();
    }
}
```

and when showing the Dialog and you need to get clicked button, let say on my condition:

```
holder.btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /** Start the Dialog Here **/

            ConfirmDialog confirmDialog = ConfirmDialog.newInstance("Titile of Dialog","Content or Description of Dialog"); //Setup Dialog
            confirmDialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)contextView).getSupportFragmentManager(), "confirmDialog"); //Show the Dialog
            confirmDialog.setOnContinueCancelClick(new ConfirmDialog.OnContinueCancelClick(){ //listen on Clicked Button
                    @Override
                    public void onContinueClicked() {
                        //Do some operation or call some functions when Continue button is Clicked
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelClicked() {
                        //Do Nothing or Do some operation or call some functions when Cancel button is Clicked
                    }
                });

        /**  END **/
    }
);
```

You can do the same with a **Custom View** or **Layout**

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private Button btnCancel, btnContinue;

    public static final String TITLE = "title", CONTENT = "content";
    private OnContinueCancelClick continueCancelClick;

    public static ConfirmDialog newInstance(String title, String content) {
        ConfirmDialog frag = new ConfirmDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TITLE, title);
        args.putString(CONTENT, content);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    public void setOnContinueCancelClick(OnContinueCancelClick continueCancelClick) {
        this.continueCancelClick = continueCancelClick;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom_layout, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //Some initialization or condition here...
        btnCancel = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel); //Intialize your Cancel Button
        btnContinue = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue); //Intialize your Continue Button

        getDialog().setTitle(getArguments().getString(TITLE)); //Set the Title

        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(continueCancelClick != null)
                    continueCancelClick.onCancelClicked(); //Return this
                dismiss(); //Close the Dialog when Done
            }
        });

        btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(continueCancelClick != null)
                    continueCancelClick.onContinueClicked(); //Return this
                dismiss(); //Close the Dialog when Done
            }
        });
    }

    public interface OnContinueCancelClick{
        void onContinueClicked();
        void onCancelClicked();
    }
}
```

This could help others so I post my solution with the help of using interface.

This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405070/how-to-use-dialog-fragment-showdialog-deprecated-android) answer by [Nepster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3496570/nepster) also help me a lot to accomplish this.

Hope this help you guys.

Comment: This definitely helped me a lot. The solution here works perfectly. There lot of questions unanswered that this solution provides. I will do a little blog on it :)

Comment: Glad It help you.

Comment: @JobM - Would you mind sharing the link for the blog you made?