# How can I settext for TextView from another class?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have an alert Dialog and I use a custom layout for this Alert Dialog, in this custom layout I have a TextView, so how can I set text for this TextView from MainActivity class?

Here is my code :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            var btn_ShowAlert =findViewById<Button>(R.id.Button)

            btn_ShowAlert.setOnClickListener {       

                txtlyric.text ="this Textview is all the problem xD "

                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lyric,null)

                dialog.setView(dialogView)
                dialog.setCancelable(true)
                dialog.show()                
            }
    }
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: please post the stacktrace thanks

Comment: Show the stack trace from logcat otherwise no one can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `widget` as in your custom `Dialog` like this before `findViewById`:

```
txtlyric = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewindialog);
```

Then you'll be able to `setText` or your stuff in your custom dialog widgets.

<sub>P.s: Note that i used `dialog` since it's your `Dialog` view.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use DialogFragment and pass necessary value into constructor

```
public class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TITLE = "dataKey";

    public static MyAlertDialogFragment newInstance(String dataToShow) {
        MyAlertDialogFragment frag = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TITLE, dataToShow);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String mDataRecieved = getArguments().getString(TITLE,"defaultTitle");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_layout, null);

        TextView mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        mTextView.setText(mDataRecieved);
        setCancelable(false);

        builder.setView(view);
        Dialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        return dialog;

    }
}
```

For more details please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405070/how-to-use-dialog-fragment-showdialog-deprecated-android)